# Can I solder a wire antenna to the exposed PCB antenna of a BBC Micro Bit to boost its bluetooth signal?

Tags: rf, antenna, wireless, bluetooth, pcb-antenna

Can I solder a wire antenna to the exposed PCB antenna of a BBC Micro Bit to boost its Bluetooth signal for both transmitting and receiving data?

[image]

Can I solder this type of 2.4G antenna to boost the Bluetooth signal of a BBC Micro Bit?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sure you *can*. Cut the trace antenna and solder a suitable 50 ohm 2.4ghz tuned antenna to it, and ground.

But should you? You may find that you have little to no performance increase. The trace antenna was tuned for best performance in the application. You may find an increase but not worth the change (unless you have a signal blocking case your trying to work around). You could get much better performance, depending on orientation and direction. Or you can just ruin the signal (assuming no soldering errors).

See https://gaidi.ca/weblog/designing-a-bluetooth-antenna-how-to-go-about-it for a practical example of someone replacing a trace antenna with a wire and some graphing of the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot! ^_^